# Can I let `rm` prompt again if I type the wrong key?

Tags: bash, cygwin, rm

## Question

Is there any way to let `rm -i` just ask again if I type in anything different than <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>n</kbd>/<kbd>N</kbd> at its prompt?

---

## Reason

Consider this small example:

```
echo "Hey, I am a file. Or at least I am IN a file." > myFile
rm -i myFile
```

This asks me *rm: remove regular file 'myFile'?*. I am German but using English all the time, so I **sometimes** <sup>1</sup> translate the question immediately before I even notice that it's in English – so I type in <kbd>j</kbd> (for *ja*, which is *yes* in German).

Typing <kbd>j</kbd> to the question, `rm` considers it as the answer *no*, so it doesn't delete the file but also does not give an error message about it, so I do not even notice that there's a problem.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Not always, of course.*

Comment: Is this in a script or at the command line?  If its in a script you likely can code arround this.

Comment: @Bowi : Instead of using the `-i` option on `rm`, use a `select` loop (see the bash man page, chapter _Compound Commands_). With this, you can accept `j` for _yes_, or whatever else you want. Also it ensures that you don't overlook the error, because you are trapped in the loop until you enter something reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
rm() {
    if [ $1 == "-i" ]; then
        while [ $ANSWER != 'j' ] && [ $ANSWER != 'J' ] && [ $ANSWER != 'n' ] && [ $ANSWER != 'N' ]; do
            read -p "rm: remove regular file '$2'? " ANSWER
            if [ $ANSWER == 'j' ] || [ $ANSWER == 'J' ]; then
                command rm "$2"
            fi
        done
        export ANSWER=:
    else
        command rm "$@"
    fi
}
```

It's basically an alias for `rm -i`, and will only accept `j, J, n, N` as answers, otherwise it will prompt again.

Other `rm` commands will not be affected by this :)

Comment: "It's basically an alias" -- "Alias" is somewhat misleading in this context because aliases in Bash are something else.

Comment: This is a nice approach, even though I'd have to take care for handling different argument combinations (`$1` is not `-i`, but eg. `-ri`) as well. And for handling wildcards in the files to delete, now that I think about it...

Answer (score 0):

The question is

> Is there any way to let `rm -i` just ask again if I type in anything different than <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>n</kbd>/<kbd>N</kbd> at its prompt?

I'm *not* going to answer this. I'm going to deal with the actual problem though (compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)).

Try to force `rm` to be in the language you may absentmindedly use. In my Debian `rm` is from GNU coreutils; `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 rm -i myFile` treats `j` *or* `y` as confirmation, so it works well regardless if one confirms in German or in English.

Use an alias (`alias rm='LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 rm'`) or a wrapper function (`rm() { LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 command rm "$@"; }`), or even a wrapper script, depending on the scope you want. Then `rm` will be in German, even if the whole general setup is English.

For this to work you need `de_DE.UTF-8` to be available. In Debian I made it available by opening `/etc/locale.gen` in a text editor (as root), uncommenting `de_DE.UTF-8`, saving the file, finally invoking `sudo locale-gen`.

You tagged [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin). I absolutely don't know how to add a German locale to Cygwin in case there is none. And I absolutely don't know if `rm` under Cygwin is localized in a way that finds `y` equivalent to `j` when in German. Frankly I don't know if it's localized at all.